# Imagen Rota PHP

Tags: php, css3, codeigniter

Amigos, tengo mi web con imagenes de tamaños pequeños por ejemplo de 96x96 px que en desarollo se muestra normal, pero cuando lo subo a produccion me sale de la siguiente manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo que hacer varias veses F5, para que se visualize la imagen, abra alguna manera de solucionar esto?

Comment: [Cómo limpiar la caché](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayuda:C%C3%B3mo_limpiar_la_cach%C3%A9)

Comment: Igual, tambien tengo que hacer varias CTRL + 5 para que salga la imagen, Conste que no es uno solo, son varias imagenes.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien marca aldanux, es un problema de cache. Si bien borrando el cache de tu navegador (o entrando como incógnito) lo vas a poder "solucionar", el resto de los clientes probablemente sigan con el mismo problema.

Lo que podes hacer es agregarle un parámetro a la URL de las imágenes para que se ignore la versión cacheada. Por ejemplo:

`<img src="https://dominio.com/imagen.jpg?v=1">`

Es una técnica que se usa mucho para lo que es contenido estático.

Comment: el parametro sale de algun lugar? o lo puedo ponder de manera manual?

Comment: @LuisVega manual, es indistinto que pongas. Es simplemente para que la URL no sea igual a la anterior, de esa forma el explorador no levanta lo que tiene en cache.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy hacerlo.